# Latin in Popular Music

Tags: contemporary-latin, song-lyrics, music

Several German bands (Helium Vola, Qntal, Estampie) sing in Latin (and often in other "dead" languages like Old French and Middle High German)*.  Is this a phenomenon unique to Germany, or are there other places where modern secular music is still being produced in Latin?

* Usually the Latin lyrics are not original but from medieval texts like the Carmina Burana or medieval writers like Alanus ab Insulis.

Comment: @Joonas_Ilmavirta I’m not sure why you rejected my edit, can you explain that to me please?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that this answer covers what you were aiming for, but I could not resist posting this as an answer.

[This YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/TranslatorCarminum/videos) has several Latin covers of popular songs. Here is a [recent cover](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cksUz_PDVk&feature=youtu.be) to "Reflection" ("Imago") from Mulan.